# Keras model.evaluate incorrect shapes

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am very confused by the `evaluate` function in Keras. All i want to calculate is the MSE loss of my test set:

```
def iterate_and_store(optimizer, nepochs=10):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=8, input_dim=3, init="glorot_normal"))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=16, init="glorot_normal"))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=32, init="glorot_normal"))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=32, init="glorot_normal"))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=16, init="glorot_normal"))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=1))
    model.add(Activation("softplus"))

    model.compile(loss='MSE', optimizer=optimizer)

    training_loss = pd.DataFrame(model.fit(input_train, output_train, nb_epoch=nepochs, batch_size=32, verbose=2).history)
    self_pred = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(input_train), columns=['estimated'])
    test_pred = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(input_test), columns=['y_hat'])
    test_loss = pd.DataFrame(model.evaluate(output_test, test_pred, verbose=2))
```

However, the line `test_loss = pd.DataFrame(model.evaluate(output_test, test_pred, verbose=2))` is throwing this error:
`ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected dense_input_40 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (10000, 1)`

Shouldn't the `evaluate` method calculate the MSE error between the predictions and the actual output of the test set?

These are what my training & test inputs and outputs look like in terms of shape:

```
input_test.shape
Out[152]: (10000, 3)
output_test.shape
Out[153]: (10000, 1)
input_train.shape
Out[154]: (10000, 3)
output_train.shape
Out[155]: (10000, 1)
```

I tried feeding the `model.evaluate` method every combination of input and output but nothing works. All my data is 10,000 rows and the input is 3 variables with 1 output that is continuous.

I just want to compare the training loss that goes lower and lower to the test loss that should be somewhat concave like this:
[image]

Comment: No. The argument of `evaluate()` is the same as `fit()`, that is, `model.evaluate(input_test, output_test)`. Read the [doc](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate).

Comment: Using your recommendation gives the following pandas error: `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` Though I don't know why since all the data are numpy arrays

Comment: `model.evaluate()` returns a scalar if no `metrics` option is given when compiling the model. A `pandas.DataFrame` cannot be constructed from a scalar. BTW, fixing this does not help since it's giving only the final MSE instead of MSE at every epoch. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to generate a graph like that, try to provide `validation_data` in `model.fit()` so that the testing set MSE **at each epoch** will be saved into the `History` object.

For example,

```
history_obj = model.fit(input_train, output_train, validation_data=(input_test, output_test))
print(pd.DataFrame(history_obj.history))
```

should give you something like this:

```
       loss  val_loss
0  0.234606  0.171870
1  0.219808  0.172064
2  0.208841  0.173415
3  0.202653  0.175946
4  0.199899  0.178934
5  0.195881  0.180141
6  0.192053  0.179317
7  0.189094  0.178707
8  0.185856  0.176857
9  0.182251  0.173282
```